# Can I get the information at which node or element or attribute the xpath failed while evaluating it against an xml

Tags: xpath

I have some xpath and I am evaluating against an XML.

```
//view/section/row
[(cell/data[@value='Other Roles'])  and
(cell/data[contains(@value,'336')]) and
(cell/data[contains(@value,'0')])   and
(cell/data[contains(@value,'320')]) and
(cell/data[contains(@value,'16')])  and
(cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]) ]
```

While doing so, the xpath might not be available say row does not have the cell with data 336 , can I get that piece of information where it failed

Any code/utils that gives this information

Answer (score 1):

In general, **No**.

Even if the result set is empty, it does not mean it fails. It is just an empty result set, which is a valid result. So as a matter of fact, your assumption is wrong, because the XPath did not fail.

If you want to check whether your XPath yiels an empty sequence, you can check using `fn:empty()`, e.g. `empty(cell/data[contains(@value,'336')])`.

Using XPath 2.0 you can also raise your own errors, using the `fn:error()` function. However, I do not see how you want to apply that in this specific example in a useful manner.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen any tools that *automatically* do this, **but *manually* performing such sanity checks can be very useful:**

First check that you're matching `views`:

```
//view
```

then `sections`:

```
//view/section
```

then `rows`:

```
//view/section/row
```

then specific `rows`:

```
//view/section/row[(cell/data[@value='Other Roles'])]
```

**...until you get to a point where reality deviates from your expectations.**  You'll then know where an adjustment must be made.